# In bash, I want to generate based on a set of words a fixed set of 4 characters output for each word and to always match

Tags: bash

I got these words

Frank_Sinatra

Dean_Martin

Ray_Charles

I want to generate 4 characters which will always match with those words and never change.

ej:

frk ) Frank_Sinatra

dnm ) Dean_Martin

Ray ) Ray_Charles

and it shall always match these 4 characters when I run it again (not random)

note:

Something like this:

String  32-bit checksum 8-bit checksum

ABC 326 0x146   70  0x46

ACB 410 0x19A   154 0x9A

BAC 350 0x15E   94  0x5E

BCA 450 0x1C2   194 0xC2

CAB 399 0x18F   143 0x8F

CBA 256 0x100   0   0x00

http://www.flounder.com/checksum.htm

Look at this command --->

echo -n Frank_Sinatra | md5sum

d0f7287be11d7bbfe53809088ea3b009  -

but instead of that long string, I wanted just 4 unique characters.

I did it like this:

echo -n "Frank_Sinatra" | md5sum > foo ; sed -i 's/./&\n@/4' foo

grep -v "@" foo > bar

Comment: *and it shall always match these 3 letters when I run it again* - can you demonstrate that process?

Comment: The names are inside a text file and I would like to just add these letters at front of those names but always match based on I guess the checksum of each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the entire program for you, but I can share some algorithm that can accomplish this. I can't guarantee that it is the most optimized algorithm.

### Problem

Generate a 3-letter identifier for each line in a text file that is unique, such that grep will only match with the intended line.

### Assumption

There exists a 3-letter identifier for each line such that grep will only match that line.

### Algorithm

- For every line in text file

  - Grab a permutation of the line, run grep on the file using that permutation.
  - If grep returns more than 2 lines, get a new permutation of the line, go back to previous step.
  - If grep returns only one line and that line matches our current line, we found a proper identifier. Store this identifier.

Comment: LTClipp Thanks! I'll try w/ grep.

Comment: Look at this ---> echo -n Frank_Sinatra | md5sum
d0f7287be11d7bbfe53809088ea3b009  - but instead of that long string I want just 3 unique characters.